# Mapserver data root

Tags: mapserver

I consolidate all my .map files and data under a root folder. (eg. c:\data)

Under the url when accessing .map file via Mapserver, instead of defining an absolute full path:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=c:/data/sample.map&layer=sample&mode=map
```

I will like to specify a relative pathing to c:\data like this:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=sample.map&layer=sample&mode=map
```

Or have some way to replace c:\data with a keyword (eg. DATA_ROOT) like this:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=DATA_ROOT/sample.map&layer=sample&mode=map
```

Is one of the above possible? Also, I am using the pre-built binaries version of Mapserver.

Comment: There is no concept of a data root, for a mapserver installation, or for a mapserver service.  You can use local references within any map file to include other map files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would not be a good idea to expose the internal directory structure in URLs, so both the .exe and the .map files are configured explicitly behind a virtual path:

```xml
<Location "/thismap">
  ScriptAlias "c:/ms4w/Apache/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe"
  SetEnv MS_MAPFILE "c:/data/config/this.map"
</Location>
<Location "/anothermap">
  ScriptAlias "c:/ms4w/Apache/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe"
  SetEnv MS_MAPFILE "c:/data/config/another.map"
</Location>
```

resulting in, e.g., `http://localhost/thismap?layer=sample&mode=map`.

And then it makes sense to use a macro for these:

```xml
<Macro MSMap $URL $config>
  <Location "$URL">
    ScriptAlias "c:/ms4w/Apache/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe"
    SetEnv MS_MAPFILE "c:/data/config/$config"
  </Location>
</Macro>

Use MSMap /thismap   this.map
...
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution will solve my problem!